# has anyone used the Hop Inject plug-in?

Tags: add-on, channel-entries, image

Looking for a way to "inject" images into channel entries without having the content administrator trying to mess with html.  I found hop inject on devot-ee, and I'm wondering if anyone has used it or a similar plug-in, and what you thought of it.  If you've used something different that you feel is better, I'd definitely be open to any recommendations.  thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Hop Inject](http://www.hopstudios.com/software/hop_inject), though I've never used, is geared more towards ads or ad like images (images unrelated to content). Do you just want images related to content? If so, than almost any of the [WYSIWYG field_types](http://devot-ee.com/search/results?keywords=WYSIWYG&collection=addons&addon_version_support=ee2) could be used and will allow images to be uploaded and inserted into copy/content without knowledge of HTML.

I'd say, [WYGWAM](http://devot-ee.com/add-ons/wygwam) by Pixel & Tonic is probably the most popular. We've used that, [Expresso](http://devot-ee.com/add-ons/expresso) by Put Your Lights On, and hope to use [Editor](http://devot-ee.com/add-ons/editor) by DevDemon on an upcoming project. WYGWAM is our primary for most projects, but we like Expresso for smaller projects or when we need a more lightweight presence. Editor just seems interesting, we're hoping to test it and see if should be added to our toolbox.

Now, if you're really looking for adding items after the fact to content, then I've heard good things about [Hop Inject](http://devot-ee.com/add-ons/hop-inject), and it can be used for pull quotes or things other than adds, but I've never used it. While, there are other ad related add-ons, I'm not certain they attack the same issue as Hop Inject, which makes it more flexible for the situation, where an image should be displayed every 4 paragraphs or a pull a quote every third paragraph.

Comment: ok great, I'm going to give WYGWAM a shot.  I'm not doing anything ad-related on this project, so I think that will work just fine.